# Delete a record from soup and salesforce Database

Tags: salesforce-sdk-android, smartstore, smartsync

Im creating a Native android application which uses salesforce integration, Ive created a custom object on Salesforce and im able perform offline sync by using smartSync, the problem is im deleting a record from the local soup using the soup id , and the record is deleted on local soup , but when i perform sync down operation the deleted record gets stored on the local database again, is there a way to delete a record in both the soup and salesforce database in offline synchronization ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the Mistake i made was i didnt send the Id generated by the Local soup,while syncing Up the data , so it couldnt complete the Delete operation.after inserting the delete field , it works fine